# Put "{" character inside variable

Tags: php

This is like the most noob question you guys will ever see in here.

I'm trying to make a shortcode for WordPress and I need to put some attributes in a link.

```
$alt = get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
$out .= '<li><a href="' . $image . '"">My Link</a></li>';
}
```

I've tried this but the code broke:

```
$alt = get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
$out .= '<li><a href="' . $image . '" data-uk-lightbox="{group:'property-gallery'}"">Foto</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Try escaping the `'`, you are breaking the concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the single quotes around `property-gallery`.

If you add a slash before each quote, it should work. e.g. `data-uk-lightbox="{group:\'property-gallery\'}"`

You also have two double quotes at the end of the `<a>` tag, so you should remove one of those as well.